# Wildcard, number of characters (arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, wildcard

Is there any way to create a list based on the number of characters of the files?
My current list goes like that

```
 rasterList  = arcpy.ListRasters("*speed*","TIF")
```

My files are
speed01
speed02
.....
speed01500

I want for example only speed01000 to speed 01500
If I could apply a wild card with 10 number of characters this would be solved easily

Comment: This sounds like pure Python so I think you should research/ask your question at [so].

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this with list comprehension and the [len function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len):

```
speed = ['speed01','speed02','speed01000','speed01500']
speed = [i for i in speed if len(i)==10]
```

Result:

```
>>speed
['speed01000', 'speed01500']
```

There are other ways to divide the list, for example see: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks):

```
numbers = [i for i in range(10)] #Create some data
numbers
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chunksize = 4 #Change
numbers = [numbers[i:i + chunksize] for i in xrange(0,len(numbers),chunksize)] #Change xrange to range for python3/ArcGIS Pro

numbers
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
for g in numbers:
   print g

[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem here is that the listRasters list cant hold more than 1000 files. So initially I cannot have a list for all my files. My problem is how to split those 1500 rasters in 1000 and 500.

Comment: @GeoF why cant it hold more? Do you get an error message?

Comment: No but when I print the list only the first 1000 show up. I think 1000 is the  limit in arcpy listRasters function

Comment: Maybe it is not printing all of them. Try `print len(speed)`, what is the output?

Comment: Hmm that seems to work. Strange but thanks a lot. Maybe they are not all printed. But either way I need to call cellstatistics function afterwards which I think has a limit of 1000 rasters. Am I correct? If thats the case I will try to use list comprehension as you suggested to divide my list

Comment: @GeoF I dont know if cellstatistics has a limit. I have added an example of how to split a list into defined chunks.